# I'm trying to create a login system using a text file

Tags: python, list, authentication

I'm trying to create a login system using a textfile so i've turned the text file into a list. When printed the textfile looks like this as i've split the rows:
`[['11Ali15', '@Tyson345', 'Alice', '15', '11'], ['11Ell16', 'Nibbles', 'Ellen', '16', '11'], ['13Ell12', 'Asdan3', 'Ellie', '12', '13']]`

This list is set out [Username,Password,Name,Age,Yeargroup] and i want to be able to make a log in system where username and password match so program can be continued.

The code i'm using at the moment is:(One of my subroutines)

```
print("--Login--")
username = input("Please enter your username:")
while len(username) == 0:
    username = input(" Please enter your username:")

password = input("Please enter your password:")
while len(password) == 0:
    password = input(" Please enter your password:")

studentlist = []
with open ("studentdetails.txt") as textfile:
    for row in textfile:
        row = row.strip ("\n")
        studentlist.append(row.split())
print (studentlist)

for everything in studentlist:       
    UserName = everything[0]
    PassWord = everything[1]

if username == UserName and password == PassWord:
    print("Logged on.")
    quizmenu()
```

But this doesn't work as it doesn't let u log in and goes round in a loop of asking username and password even when they're entered correctly.

Comment: But why though? Almost anything else would be easier than a .txt file

Comment: It's a school programming task and i'm required to use a text file

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) It is not important if you are reading from file or not. Use string for file's content.

Comment: I've got the answer i needed for my programme to work the way i want to the only thing wrong was my indentation

Comment: @a..m.r.cuikau Remeber it for the next time. Accept the answer if it gave you a solution.

Comment: @ElisByberi You can't for a period of time but i accepted it as soon as i could

Comment: @a..m.r.cuikau Ok! By the way Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is off. It should be checking for Username and Password for each user in the text file, which would be like the following:

```
for everything in studentlist:       
    UserName = everything[0]
    PassWord = everything[1]

    if username == UserName and password == PassWord:
        print("Logged on.")
        quizmenu()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have username and password data in test.txt file . You can use the below function to validate user account

```
def validateUserAccount():
    global index_num,userName,passWord,balances,username,password
    username=input("Enter your username : ")
    password=input("Enter your password : ")
    fileRead=open('test.txt','r')
    flag=False
    while True:
        line=fileRead.readline()
        lineLength=len(line)
        if lineLength==0:
            break
        lineItem=line.split()
        if username.strip()==lineItem[0] and password.strip()==lineItem[1] :
            print("Hello !",username," you have logged in successfully.")
            flag=True
            break
    if flag==False:
        print("The user is not found.Please re-enter your username and password.")
        validateUserAccount()
```